# Partition error (Fdisk/Parted)

Tags: partition, parted, partition-table

I was creating a partition using the **parted** command and i used the **mkpart** option to create a new primary partition. But i got an unusual error message while doing this. **This is my output:**

```
(parted) print
Model: ATA VBOX HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 729GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:
Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  300GB   300GB   primary   ext4         boot

(parted) mkpart
Partition type? primary/extended? primary
File system type? ext4
Start? 1050
End? 30000
Warning: You requested a partition from 1050MB to 30.0GB (sector 2050781..58593750). The closest location we can manage is 300GB to 300GB (sector 585936896..585936896).
Is this still acceptable to you?
Yes/No?
```

- I did the start at 1050 (because the previous partition starts at 1049) and i did the end at 30GB as i wanted it (30000MB)
- I have been told that i have to do the Start value as one more than the previous partition's start value and i should do the end value at the size i want in MB as parted uses MB by default.

Comment: I apologize for leading you astray. When I last messaged you I said a 30GB partition would be the start _of that partition_, as in roughly 1 unit  more then the end of the previous partition, plus 30 GB worth of units. user derobert has the answer. You need to have the start be 1 sector more than the end of the previous partition.

Comment: Its cool, im still learning lol anyways so my current understanding is that for the start i should make it more more digit than the previous partitions start. And for the end i should do it the actual size i want it to be. Isnt this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Partitions must not overlap, so the start of the second partition must be at least one sector after (larger number) than the *last* sector of the first partition. Not the *first* sector, the *last*.

Your first partition starts at offset 1049kb and is 300GB in size. Parted is asking you for a start position in MB; your first partition runs from (approximately) 1 through 300000 MB (the "end" position, multiplied by 1000 to convert from GB to MB). So 1050 would be in the middle of that, hence not allowed.

You can have parted print the sizes entirely in MB by running `unit MB` before `print`. That will make it easier to see what is happening and the right numbers to use. You could switch to sectors with `unit s`, if you need to get the positioning perfect.

Comment: Firstly thanks for the answer man, and Im still not understanding it could you explain to me what i would write for the start and end value or how i can work out what to put for them?

Comment: @Qasim If you put '300GB' as the start and '330GB' as the end, that should work, giving you a 30GB partition. Or switch it to MB, and run print again to see the values to use.

Comment: Hm ok i see, but how does this work, i just need you to explain to me what i should add for my start and end values and why. Or how i could calculate the start and end im just trying to get a good understanding of it

Comment: @Qasim You start partition 2 where partition 1 ended. Your partition 1 ends at 300GB, so that's what you'd use a start value for partition 2.

Comment: Ok and where would i end it?

Comment: @Qasim Where you end it determines how large it is. So if you want 30GB of space in the partition, you end it at start+30GB (e.g., 330GB if it starts at 300GB)

Comment: Ah i see thanks a lot man ive been tryna understand this for a few days now and its been frustrating so thanks alot :)